# laravel 5.7 many to many with custome table name

Tags: laravel, eloquent, many-to-many

Goods Model

```
class goods extends Model
{
  protected $table = "goods";
  public function sales(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\sales', 'sales_details', 'goods', 'sales');
  }
}
```

Sales Model

```
class sales extends Model
{
  protected $table = "sales";
  public function goods(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\goods','sales_details','sales','goods');
  }
}
```

i also make this model but i don't know if i ever need it or not

```
class salesDetail extends Model
    {
      protected $table = "sales_details";
    }
```

my controller

```
public function test()
    {
      $goods = goods::all();
      return view('test',compact('goods'));
    }
```

my test.blade.php

```
@foreach($goods as $data)
    <li><strong>{{ $data->name }}</strong> - {{ $data->company->kind }} {{ $data->company->name }}</li>
    <p>{{ $goods->sales }}</p>
  @endforeach
```

i connect goods table with sales table with many to many without following laravel naming. 
This is my table contents

```
goods
-id
-name

sales
-id
-date

sales_details
-goods
-sales
-qty
-price
```

and i couldn't make it work. i just wanted to show the result like this

```
sales -id
sales - date
goods - name
sales_details - qty
sales_details - price
```

this should be the result
[image: this should be the result]

Comment: whats the error message?

Comment: @MONSTEEEER Property [sales] does not exist on this collection instance.

Comment: can you post you code in your controller? maybe you have error in your code.

Comment: @MONSTEEEER i haven't touch my controller

Comment: You dont need **Model** for your pivot table.

Comment: Can you post your code in your controller?

Comment: just edited my post

Comment: I can't see where you're using `sales` in your controller code. Please can you show the code where you're trying to access `->sales` i.e. the code that is causing the `Property [sales] does not exist on this collection instance` error?

Comment: just edited my post @RossWilson

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$data->sales`?

Comment: saves? where's saves come from?

Comment: My bad, that was just a typo. I've updated it now. This should fix the error but I doubt it will give you what you want since the `sales()` relationship is a `belongsToMany` which will return a collection. Am I correct in assuming you want to display the `sales` field from the `sales_details` table here?

Comment: it doesn't work with same error message. so it should have shown the result like on 1/1/2019 i bought stuffs a with 3 piece, stuffs b with 5 piece and stuff c with only 1 piece.... the 'stuffs' came from table goods. the date came from table sales... and each qty of the item came from sales_details

Comment: So you've changed `<p>{{ $goods->sales }}</p>` to be `<p>{{ $data->sales }}</p>` and you're still getting the same error? Can you show the query you used to display the example output in your question?

Comment: it work but the result shown as json.... i couldn't show only date.... this are the error message **Property [date] does not exist on this collection instance.**

Comment: Yes, this is because sales is a belongsToMany (many-to-many) relationship so it's going to return a collection instead of a single instance. You'll need to loop through `$data->sales`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `@foreach` loop you're trying to access `sales` on the collection of goods rather than the instance in the loop. Also, because the `sales()` relationship is a belongsToMany (many-to-many) you're going to get a collection and not a single instance so you're going to need to loop through them as well e.g.

```
@foreach($goods as $data)
    <li>
        <strong>{{ $data->name }}</strong> - {{ $data->company->kind }} {{ $data->company->name }}

        @foreach($data->sales as $sale)
            <p>{{ $sale->date }} - {{ $sale->pivot->qty }}</p>
        @endforeach
    </li>
@endforeach
```

To access data from your pivot table you will first need to tell Laravel to include that information in the relationship:

```
public function sales()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\sales', 'sales_details', 'goods', 'sales')
        ->withPivot('qty', 'price');
}
```

You should also add the `withPivot` method to the `good()` relationship in the `sales` class as well.

Then you'll be able access the information from the `pivot` property. This is happening in the example above with `{{ $sale->pivot->qty }}`.

[Many to many docs (scroll down to **Retrieving Intermediate Table Columns** )](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

Comment: And how do i get the data from sales_details table?

Comment: @MartinChristopher I have updated my answer to show how to get the pivot information.